# Running a FIFO Simulation

Tags: c

I am trying to run a simulation program to test the FIFO algorithm, however my program is just crashing. this is the main, other functions not shown. Can anyone spot for me the problem.Am not so familiar with using the main Argument[ int main(int argc, char *argv[])]
I have the testing files in a folder

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
   FILE *stream;

  if (argc != 3)
 {
 printf("The format is: pager file_name memory_size.\n");
 //exit(1);
 }

  printf("File used %s, resident set size %d\n", argv[1], atoi(argv[2]));

 if ((stream = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL)
{
  perror("File open failed");
 //exit(1);
 }
  mem_size = atoi(argv[2]);
 start_simulation(stream);
 fclose(stream);
 system("pause");
}
```

Comment: i'm guessing `mem_size` is a global variable and you don't have any syntax errors.

Comment: Can you step through with gdb to find out on which line it crashes?

Comment: How exactly does it crash? If you comment your code, line by line but keeping it compilable, when it stops crashing?

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment the calls to exit.

```
if (argc != 3) {
 // insufficient arguments passed..print error and exit.
 printf("The format is: pager file_name memory_size.\n");
 exit(1);
}
```

In your case (exit commented) if you don't provide command line arguments, `argv[1]` will be `NULL` and this can cause crash when used in `fopen`

Comment: Well just noticed that the its not opening the file stream.if i un comment the exit(1), it exits imediately.

Comment: Its exiting because you are not providing enough cmd-line args and that is what we want.

Comment: Dev compiler, is it possible to be a compiler problem. All the code seems fine

Comment: Compile the program use the IDE and run it from the DOS prompt as: `C:\>prg.exe file_name mem_size` after you go to the dir that has the executable.